# CSS3 keyframes ease-in box then ease-out

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I am having a look at CSS3 keyframes and want to have a box that eases in then eases out for the specified iteration-count, this is what I have so far it eases in then disappears then eases in again.
I want the box to ease in then ease out.  [See my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/4fWSa/). What do I need to do to achieve this?

```
<div id="content">
    <span class="aniamte"></span>
</div> 

@keyframes reset {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes fade-in {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    60% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
.aniamte {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    animation-name: reset, fade-in;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: 5;
    animation-delay: 0, 1s;    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `animation-direction:alternate`, but your question is not very clear. This will make your element use the keyframes from `0%` to `100%` for the specified duration then go from `100%` to `0%` after the first iteration is complete

```
@keyframes fade-in {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
.animate {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    animation-name: fade-in;
    animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-direction:alternate;
    animation-iteration-count: 5;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4fWSa/1/)